# Added new field on my Local Storage Jquery code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I tried adding another Textarea on my html the local storage is not working but when it's only one it's working fine. I also tried adding a new jQuery code on my existing but still not working. Kindly see the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/rico-p-buenviaje/pen/WNOyqKV) to try my original code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var storage = false;
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.list != undefined) {
      list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));
      if (Object.keys(list).length > 0) {
        $('title').text("You have (" + Object.keys(list).length + ") item/s on your ToDo List");
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(list).length; i++) {
        Object.keys(list)[i]
        $('.sNote').append(
          '<div class="list-item" data-postid="' + Object.keys(list)[i] + '">' + list[(Object.keys(list)[i])] +
          '</div><div class="close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>'
        );
      }
    } else {
      var list = {};
    }
    storage = true;
  } else {
    // No Local Storage
    var list = {};
  }

  function randChar(s) {
    e = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < s; i++) {
      e += String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26));
    }
    return e;
  }
  $('.aNote').on('click', function() {
    i = $('.iNote-items').val();
    if (i != "") {
      uniqid = Date.now();
      id = (uniqid / 1231).toString().split(".")[1] + randChar(4);
      list[id] = i;
      $('title').text("You have (" + Object.keys(list).length + ") item/s on your ToDo List");
      if (storage) {
        localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));
      }
      $('.iNote-items').val("");
      $('.sNote').append(
        '<div class="list-item" data-postid="' + id + '">' + i +
        '</div><div class="close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>'
      );
    } else {
      $('.iNote-items').focus();
    }
  });
  $('.iNote-items').keypress('', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      $('.aNote').click();
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
    //console.log("test");
    delete list[$(this).prev('.list-item').attr('data-postid')];
    if (storage) {
      localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));
    }
    $(this).prev(".list-item").remove();
    $(this).remove()
    if (Object.keys(list).length > 0) {
      $('title').text("You have (" + Object.keys(list).length + ") item/s on your ToDo List");
    } else {
      $('title').text('ToDo List');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="iNote-c">
  <div class="iNote-inputs">
    <textarea class="hrd" rows="3"></textarea>
    <textarea class="iNote-items" rows="3"></textarea>
    <div class="aNote">Save</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sNote"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: First line in the 'for' loop `Object.keys(list)[i]` looks like it should be commented-out. Is that causing a problem?

Comment: I use 'for' loop when I only use 1 textarea but how about 2 textarea can you help me how to do it?

Comment: here's the codepen link so you can see its working but the other textarea is not working fine